# Clarification on tag usage

Tags: discussion

I'm new to the community and not sure of accepted standards yet, but I'd like to help and not make a nuisance of myself.

I made an edit suggestion to add the Hiberno-English tag to [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51427/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-top-of-the-morning-to-you), but it was rejected because

> "This edit introduces tags that do not help to define the topic of the question. Tags should help to describe what the question is about, not just what it contains".

I looked at some other questions that have that tag, and there are a few asking about specific phrases [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/264241/what-words-do-children-of-english-native-speakers-use-for-kid-child-etc), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151158/where-does-the-irish-idiom-at-all-at-all-come-from), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160280/why-do-we-say-county-durham), rather than about the dialect as a whole.

Could I get clarification on where dialect tags should/shouldn't be used?

Comment: Can you add a link to the post where you wanted to add the Hiberno-English tag?

Comment: @DanBron, fixed.

Comment: I've added the tag to the post (there's no reason it should not have been). That's the immediate problem solved. I'll let my better-informed colleagues comment on the broader policy question. My take is (obviously) that we can add <Regional>-English tags to any question specifically focused on the dialect of English spoken in that region.

Comment: +1 for effort. I remember your edit. I had rejected it on an impulse. But after I checked the tag wiki, realized it was my bad. Apologies. Welcome to ELU, friend :)

Comment: Just curious: how did you know the OP's context was Hiberno-English?

Comment: @Lawrence Same way the top answerer did: this is a stereotypically Irish phrase. It's something you picture a drunk leprechaun saying while hunting for four-leaved clovers. In fact, it's gotten *so* cliche, that, as that top answer points out, it's become disfavored in Ireland, and rarely does anyone use it anymore.